# Hiding unnecessary stuff of JSONOject in swagger

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

```
@XmlElement(name = "dummyAttrib")
@ApiModelProperty(value = "dummyAttrib")

JSONObject dummyAttrib = new JSONObject();
//setter and getter
```

Now., When I am accessing My Application in Swagger the dummy attribute looks like

```
"dummyAttrib": {
    "values": "java.util.Collection<V>",
    "empty": false,
    "size": 0,
    "entrySet": "Set[java.util.Map.java.util.Map$Entry<K, V>]",
    "keySet": [
      "K"
    ]
}
```

So While entering input for the dummyAttrib, it is bit difficult to delete the entire default stuff and add our own stuff.

Can any one please suggest me to hide the default data given by Swagger?

I want something like

```
"dummyAttrib":{}
```

So that I can add my stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your annotation, you can choose the dataType that you want to map to.  So for example:

```
@XmlElement(name = "dummyAttrib")
@ApiModelProperty(value = "dummyAttrib", dataType = "java.lang.Object)

JSONObject dummyAttrib = new JSONObject();
```

Which will look like this:

```
{
  "MyModel" : {
    "type" : "object",
    "properties" : {
      "dummyAttrib" : {
        "type" : "object",
        "description" : "dummyAttrib"
      }
    }
  }
}
```